# Added device tag in storyboard file with Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, xcode8

This device tag was added to one of my storyboards files, I didn't see it before. I'm using `Xcode 8.3`.
What does it mean? I'm wondering if it should be committed or not.

```
<device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
     <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>  
</device>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing serious.
It's based on the selected option of the storyboard/xib:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have xCode *not* add this tag at all? Right now I have to remember to remove it every time I'm about to commit.